# Returning a structure referencing a new &str

Tags: string, reference, rust

I'm currently writing a program and at some point I have to deal with a structure containing `&str` values. Let's consider it has this look:

```
struct Book<'a> {
    url: &'a str,
}
```

I have a function that fetches a book from a remote storage and returns an URL pointing to that book, which looks like this:

```
fn fetch_book<'a>(id: u64) -> Book<'a> {
  // do some stuff to get a 'key' variable that allows to access the book
  Book {
    // Here we turn the formatted String into an &str
    url: &format!("https://<ip-address>/books?id={}&key={}", id, key)
  }
}
```

This function won't compile because Rust tells we are returning a value that references data owned by the current function.

So, what can I do to make this function works properly (without going `unsafe`)?

Comment: Looks like you want `String` instead of `&str` as the type of `url`.

Comment: Indeed, but I'd like to _not_ store a `String` in my structure - the strings in there are not supposed to be mutable.

Comment: @ClementNerma You *build* the URL, it's not borrowed from elsewhere. You have to store it somewhere, mutable or not. The fact `String` is mutable is just a bonus here, the important point is that it owns the str

Comment: That's true, but I can't figure out _why_ I can't put this new `&str` inside this structure, as it should live long enough for that.

Comment: @ClementNerma `&str` is a reference to *something*, as the `&` hints at. You can't just chuck the string away and keep the slice version of it.

Comment: The reason you want the owned type (`String`) is for owned purposes, not for mutability (that's a completely different thing)

Comment: At the end of the function, the valus that are created are either dropped or moved. If you don't move the str (ie return it in an owning structure), it's dropped and references to it makes no sense anymore.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I see your point, that's why I was struggling at. Thanks for the explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @DenysSéguret pointed out in the comments:

> At the end of the function, the values that are created are either dropped or moved. If you don't move the `str` (ie return it in an owning structure), it's dropped and references to it makes no sense anymore.

Plus, according to [this question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-how-to-return-str-from-format/12838) posted on Rust's users forum, it is indeed not possible to return a `&str` from a "freshly-generated" string.